# EF Core : complex delete case (delete multiple rows in order)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, sql-delete

I have this table with 4 objects that descend hierarchically from a commun type, in order to simplify the question lets call them: `A, B, C, D`.

The types have the following foreign key relationships:

- B with one A with many B's with A_id as foreign key.
- C with one B with many C's with B_id as foreign key.
- D with one C with many D's with C_id as foreign key.

How do I delete an A containing multiple B's which contain multiple C's also with multiple D's using EF Core?

Because this in the same table and all relations create multiple cascade paths, Cascade Delete doesn't work.

I know it works if I delete all C's first and then call `SaveChanges`, then all D's and call `SaveChanges` again, and so on .. making me access the DB 4 times to delete.

I tried adding to `Context.Remove()` by order of deletion, first C's etc and then calling `SaveChanges` once and it didn't work.

I know if I create a SQL query with the deletions sorted first C's then D's, etc it works, but I wanted to see if there was another way to do this..

Adding code:

```
EntityTypeBuilder<BaseModel> base= modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>();

        base.ToTable("Models", BLSchema);

        base.HasKey(k => k.Id);            

        base.HasDiscriminator<string>(ModelConst.Type)                
            .HasValue<AModel>(TasksConst.TypesConst.A)
            .HasValue<BModel>(TasksConst.TypesConst.B)
            .HasValue<CModel>(TasksConst.TypesConst.C)
            .HasValue<DModel>(TasksConst.TypesConst.D);       

        base.Property(p => p.CreatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
        base.Property(p => p.UpdatedAt)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

EntityTypeBuilder<AModel> a= modelBuilder.Entity<AModel>();

        a.HasIndex(x => new { x.Name, x.ProjectId, x.Type })
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter($"[{ModelConst.Type}] = '{ModelConst.TypesConst.A}'");

        a.HasMany(x => x.Bs)
            .WithOne(x => x.A)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.AId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);                 

 EntityTypeBuilder<BModel> b= modelBuilder.Entity<BModel>();

        b.HasIndex(x => new { x.Name, x.ProjectId, x.Type, x.AId})
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter($"[{ModelConst.Type}] = '{ModelConst.TypesConst.B}'");

        b.HasMany(x => x.Cs)
            .WithOne(x => x.B)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.BId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

 EntityTypeBuilder<CModel> c= modelBuilder.Entity<CModel>();

        c.HasIndex(x => new { x.Name, x.ProjectId, x.Type, x.BId })
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter($"[{ModelConst.Type}] = '{ModelConst.TypesConst.C}'");

        c.HasMany(x => x.Ds)
            .WithOne(x => x.C)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.CId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

 EntityTypeBuilder<DModel> d= modelBuilder.Entity<DModel>();

        d.HasIndex(x => new { x.Name, x.ProjectId, x.Type, x.CId })
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter($"[{ModelConst.Type}] = '{ModelConst.TypesConst.D}'");
```

Compliments

Comment: EF Core deals with entities, not tables and rows. Cascade delete works, but again, you aren't dealing with tables and rows. If you mark all loaded entities as deleted and call `SaveChanges`, EF Core will generate `DELETE` statements for all of them.

Comment: It is either 4 round trips, a raw sql query, or a stored procedure.

Comment: On the other hand `this table with 4 different row types discriminated:` and `The types have the following relationships:` that's probably a smell. Relations in a database are defined by the tables and foreign keys. Not programmer assumptions. Foreign keys *can* refer to the same table so cascade deletes could work, even though they'd be *very* inefficient. When you load the *objects* though, even the quirkiest relations should be translated to plain old object and collection properties.

Comment: `if I delete all C's first and then SaveChanges, then all D's and SaveChange` you don't have to do that. Find all objects and call `Delete` on them, then make a single call to `SaveChanges`. If you want a better solution, post your actual table schema and classes. For example, if you had a self-referencing hierarchy you could create a recursive CTE and a DELETE to delete all related rows with one call. If you use `hierarchyid` you can avoid the CTE and delete everything with a key that starts with the root's key, a simple range search

Comment: @MarchalPT *B must have A as parent* - Just so it's clear, are you talking about an C# object inheritance hierarchy (Isosceles is-a Triangle is-a Shape), or a data relational (LineItem has-a Order has-a Customer) one?

Comment: Choose performance. Always. You don't want to have many round-trips. Thus, create a stored procedure and execute it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Cascade Delete wont work here because updateing the DB with it throws an exception saying multiple cascade paths do to the nature of the relations. Also masrking them marking the for delete it will delete them in a random order making the foreign keys to throw exceptions. What are you talking about in your second comment? Programmer assumptions? The discriminated is used for hierarchy porpuses, all those types descend hierarchically from a commun object.

Comment: You didn't provide any information so it's impossible to help. You talk about row types instead of classes and entities, so it's highly likely the problem is caused by confusion more than anything. There are no row types. It's the ORM's job to map types, which may inherit from each other, to tables. When you work on the ORM side there are no rows. When you work on the database side there's no inheritance.

Comment: @CaiusJard Im talking about foreign key relations there, I didnt metioned but all those types also descend from a commun object that is way the are all in the same table.

Comment: Oh, so it's both? In your app you have a D, which is-a A, and D also has-a parent/child A, eg (Electrician is-a Human) has-a (Plasterer is-a Human) daughter, and you want to delete electrician and daughter..

Comment: @MarchalPT show, don't tell. Shows us the types and tables, don't tell us how they look one-comment-per-day. Your comments can't be copied, compiled, reproduced and tested. Code can

Comment: No, lets say, A, B, C, D descend from object H, but besides having common properties, each one is different from each other, for example A is similar to D, but A can have multiple B's while D does not contain any relations. Other example A can have multiple B's and B can have multiple C's, but can't have multiple B's like A and also A can't have multiple C's, only B. You get it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updating my Question..